# Deploying Angular2 on Heroku yields 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected Token <' on all external references

Tags: node.js, angular, express, heroku

I'm trying to deploy an angular4 app on Heroku. But I get errors on all my `.js` references linked from my `.html`.

The errors are as such

```
16:29:54.613 myapp.herokuapp.com/:1 Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://myapp.herokuapp.com/assets/style/bootstrap.css".
16:29:54.646 jquery-1.10.2.min.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
16:29:54.647 myapp.herokuapp.com/:1 Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://myapp.herokuapp.com/styles.d41d8cd98f00b204e980.bundle.css".
16:29:54.685 bootstrap.min.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
16:29:54.743 jquery.bxslider.min.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
16:29:54.744 jquery.centralized.min.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
16:29:54.776 jquery.fixedonlater.min.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
16:29:54.865 jquery.hashloader.min.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
16:29:54.867 jquery.mixitup.min.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
16:29:54.868 jquery.nav.min.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
16:29:54.869 jquery.parallax-1.1.3.min.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
16:29:54.946 jquery.responsivevideos.min.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
16:29:54.947 jquery.scrollTo.min.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
16:29:54.948 jquery.tweet.min.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
16:29:54.999 jquery.tweetCarousel.min.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
16:29:55.001 holder.min.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
16:29:55.003 application.min.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
16:29:55.005 inline.230e19a62ca0cc6cf333.bundle.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
16:29:55.007 polyfills.2a6cee40ee8af30fbaec.bundle.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
16:29:55.018 vendor.20becde8ac8acd1f3058.bundle.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
16:29:55.019 main.f037d06044d7934ea073.bundle.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

All these files exist in my `src/client/assets/js/` directory.

My `server.js` is as such

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');

const root = './dist/public';
const pub = process.env.PUBLIC || `${root}`;
const app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/public/assets')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/public')));

app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(`index.html`, { root: pub });
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.set('port', port);
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`API running on localhost:${port}`));
```

Am I missing something? The app works just fine locally.

Comment: Taking into account both the `text/html` and the `Unexpected token <` I can't help but thinking all your resources are being served up with HTML contents. Take a look at the contents of the files coming over the wire. They might be error pages but I'm guessing it's more likely they're all copies of `index.html` being served up because `express.static` isn't finding the files.

Comment: That's kind of interesting. If I open the `sources` in chromes dev tools, each file source opens and looks exactly like my `index.html`.

Comment: Maybe `app.get('/*')` is returning only my `index.html`? Instead of what's in my `assets`??

Comment: If `express.static` doesn't find a file it just calls `next()` to pass control on to the next piece of middleware, which in your case is the `'/*'` `get` handler. I suggest making that handler more specific and creating a 404 handler too, see https://expressjs.com/en/starter/faq.html . Neither of which will fix your problem, that's simply a matter of figuring out why `server.js` can't find those files. If you're sure the paths are all correct it might be a permissions issue. I'm not sure what you meant by files existing in `src/client/assets/js/`, seems you need them in `dist/public`.

Answer (score 0):

This had everything to do with the file location of where my dyno was executing my script from. All my files served 'statically' from my `server.js` needed to be referenced relative to `server.js`.